# Magento 2 How to Remove the Checkout Login Popup?

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout

Is there a way of removing the checkout login popup via the layout? So the customer can use the auto login email form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this. The way I would remove the login pop up from the checkout page would be like this:

Create a new following `Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` under `app/design/frontend/[your_theme]`.

Then add the following to to the file you just created.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="authentication" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here is a quick explaination of what the code above does:

1. The name `checkout_index_index` references a route which in this case
   is `checkout/index/index`.
2. Then you reference the container (`content`) and block (`checkout.root`) which are the sections of
   the page you want to work on.
3. The item you want to remove is authentication, so you need to declare its parents hierarchy other wise it will not work.
4. Then inside the item in this case `authentication` you add the another item called `config` and inside that item you add another one called `componentDisable` of type `boolean` and value of `true`, this is what does the trick.

**Don't forget to clear you layout caches and this should work.**

```
php bin/magento cache:clean layout
```

Comment: this is not working in my case. @andre

Comment: Also not working here. Do we need to disable/enable anything in the config to go with this?

Comment: To everyone who has commented: this method is simply outdated. Was working for me on Magento 2.1. Now using Magento 2.2.3 and it doesn't work at all.

Comment: @JoshuaFlood it working in magento 2.2.4, if you checking view source then you might get authenticate popup content best to add `<referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="authentication-popup" remove="true"/>
</referenceContainer> ` in xml

Answer (score 9):

Place that code block in your theme default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="authentication-popup" remove="true"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the file related to it in Magento 2.2x

`Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage.html`

Or `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage.html`

So you have to edit/overload the file in
`app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/onepage.html`

Source- https://tutes.in/how-to-remove-sign-in-popup-from-magento-2-checkout-page/